# How can I eliminate the top-level URL slug in WordPress while still being able to access child pages, particularly three levels deep or more?

Tags: php, wordpress, url

Is this a limitation inherent to WordPress? For instance, when we have a URL structure with three levels of hierarchy, is it not possible to remove the first level? Currently, I must maintain the permalink structure as "/%postname%/" as required. Specifically, I have a parent page titled "tournament-name" with children and grandchildren. When attempting to access a child page URL without including the grandparent URL slug but including the parent URL slug, it automatically redirects to include the grandparent URL slug.

For example: I need to access the existing page http://local.test.com/tournament-name/team-name/players/ using the URL http://local.test.com/team-name/players/   - that is without 'tournament-name' URL keyword.

This change is for search engine optimization.

I'm able to remove the `tournament-name` and get it rediredted to http://local.test.com/team-name/players/. But wordpress automatically redirects it back to http://local.test.com/tournament-name/team-name/players/ - leading to an infinite loop. Also I need to make sure the page http://local.test.com/tournament-name/team-name/players/  shows the same content as http://local.test.com/tournament-name/team-name/players/

The code I tried is given below

```
function custom_remove_parent_page_slug() {
    // List of parent pages for which you want to remove the slug
    $parent_pages = array(
        'tournament-name'
    );

    global $wp;

    $requested_url = home_url( $wp->request );

    foreach ( $parent_pages as $parent_page ) {
        $parent_page_url = home_url( $parent_page );

        // Check if the requested URL starts with the parent page URL
        if ( strpos( $requested_url, $parent_page_url ) === 0 ) {
            // Remove the parent page slug from the URL

            $child_page_url = str_replace( $parent_page_url, home_url(), $requested_url );

            // Check if the child page URL is different from the requested URL
            if ( $child_page_url !== $requested_url ) {
                // Redirect with a 301 status code
                wp_redirect( $child_page_url, 301 );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'custom_remove_parent_page_slug' );
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look in permalink structure in settings?

Comment: Yes, Drashti. As mentioned in the question - I've changed it to "/%postname%/" - which got applied to posts.
But I'm unable to change the URL structure of pages.

Comment: okay, then the only option according to me is manually change link from edit page.
Reference: [link] https://wbcomdesigns.com/how-to-remove-parent-slug-from-child-page-url-in-wordpress/

Comment: This could be a comment instead of answer.